# Can arguments be converted in function template in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

For example, I have a function template:

`template<typename T> void foo(T a, T b, T &c);`

What if I pass `int, double, double` to it? In Xcode it reports an error. So does that mean I cannot pass arguments with different types for one template type?

In another situation, If I call `foo<double>(double, int, int)`, it is an error. But `foo<int>(double, int, int)` will be fine. Does this problem relate to the reference type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass different types without explicitly specifying the type. Templates are strongly typed, and type deduction will fail if the types don't match perfectly.

In the first example you are specifying the template type and therefore explictly instantiate the template with a `double`

```
foo<double>(T, T, T&)
```

so the function takes as parameters `(double, double, double&)`. The example doesn't work because the compiler **does not** perform type conversions for fundamental type references (i.e., it is illegal to have `int n; double& c = n;` or the other way around), and you are passing an `int` as the last argument, which cannot bind to the `double&` reference.

The second example

```
foo<int>(T, T, T&)
```

is OK, you specify the type explicitly and instantiate the function with parameters `(int, int, int&)`. Now the compiler performs the required conversions (`double`-to-`int`) for the first parameter; there is no conversion performed for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

No, of course, `T` cannot be both `int` and `double` at the same time. The functions parameters do not match the arguments of your call.

Answer (score 0):

If you need different parameter types in your template function use this as an example

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
void add( A a, B b, C& c ) {
    c = static_cast<C>( a + b );
}
```

If you are working with template types that are pointers to objects then you may need to use dynamic_cast instead.